# How to pull a file from Github to a Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: node.js, git, github, digital-ocean

I'm trying to figure out how to get a file(s) from a Github repo to Digital Ocean droplet. The repo was cloned, but after committing new changes to Github from my my local machine, I don't know how to get the file(s) from Github to my droplet. I have an SSH connection. When I run git pull, it throws an error.

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    app.js
Please, commit  your changes or stash them before you can merge.
```

I have tried various solutions I found online but nothing is working.

I would appreciate any help or a link to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are modifying the repository on the droplet and also on your machine, so you have merge conflicts.

If you don't want to lose your changes on your droplet you can do a stash first:

```
git stash
git pull
git stash apply
```

That should work without losing any data but you probably want to do a `git diff` first in order to see if you need your changes from the droplet, if not (and if you didn't write them) it is possible you are versioning some file you don't want on git, like cache/temporary files.

Comment: Thanks @Gesper. Fantastic! This works. Thanks for taking the time.